# Proving each subsequent term equal to one another in an equation

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Q. The maximum value of $\cos x_1\cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n$ under restrictions $0\le x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\cot x_1 \cdot \cot x_2 \cdot \cot x_3...\cot x_n=1$.

MY ATTEMPT:

From question, we get $$\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n=\sin x_1 \cdot \sin x_2 \cdot \sin x_3...\sin x_n ...(1)$$
Using AM,GM inequality, we get:
$$\frac{\cos x_1+\cos x_2+\cos x_3+...+\cos x_n}{n}=\sqrt[n]{\cos x_1\cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n}\,\,\,...(2)$$
$$\frac{\sin x_1 +\sin x_2+\sin x_3+...+\sin x_n}{n}=\sqrt[n]{\sin x_1 \cdot \sin x_2 \cdot \sin x_3...\sin x_n}\,\,\,...(3)$$

The RHS term in equations $(2)\,\,,(3)$ are equal by using equation $(1)$.
So we get:
$$\cos x_1+\cos x_2+\cos x_3+...+\cos x_n=\sin x_1 +\sin x_2+\sin x_3+...+\sin x_n$$
Now i notice that if i somehow prove that $\sin x_1=\cos x_1,\,\,\sin x_2=\cos x_2,...,\,\,\sin x_n=\cos x_n$, so i get every angle as '$\frac\pi 4$'
$$\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n=\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\biggr)^n=\biggl(\frac{1}{ 2^\frac{n}{2}}\biggr)$$;
Which is the answer. But i am unsure how to prove such thing or is it even possible with how much i have attempted. Also if possible, give any other solution to the question which is shorter/interesting.

Comment: how did you get equality in equations (2)and (3)  did you miss a $\ge $?

Comment: It seems to me that the your attempt is incorrect (but your answer of your own question below is correct). You can deduce nothing from 2 inequality (2) and (3).

Comment: I thought for maximum value of $$(\cos x_1\cos x_2\cos x_3...\cos x_n)^(1/n)$$, it would be equal to its arithmetic mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Arithmetic Geomeyric Inequality

$\displaystyle \sec^2(x_{i})=1+\tan^2(x_{i})\geq 2\tan(x_{i})$

$\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{i=1}\sec^2(x_{i})\geq \prod^{n}_{i=1}2\tan(x_{i})=2^{n}$

$\displaystyle \prod^{n}_{i=1}\cos(x_{i})\leq \frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}$

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution to the question, if anyone is interested:

We know from question:
$$\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n=\sin x_1 \cdot \sin x_2 \cdot \sin x_3...\sin x_n ...(1)$$
Let $$x=\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n$$
$$x^2=(\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n)^2$$
$$x^2=(\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n)(\cos x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot \cos x_3...\cos x_n)$$
$$x^2=(\cos x_1 \cdot \sin x_1 \cdot \cos x_2 \cdot\sin x_2\cdot \cos x_3 \cdot \sin x_3 ...\cos x_n \cdot \sin x_n)$$
$$x^2=\frac{1}{2^n}(\sin 2x_1 \cdot \sin 2x_2 ...\sin 2x_n)$$
Maximum value of $(\sin 2x_1 \cdot \sin 2x_2 ...\sin 2x_n)=1$
$$x=\biggl(\frac{1}{ 2^\frac{n}{2}}\biggr)$$

Comment: That was nice..